# npm ERR! code E500 npm ERR! 500 Internal Server Error - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap

Tags: npm

Hello guy I got this error when i try to use npm install

npm ERR! code E500
npm ERR! 500 Internal Server Error - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap

My node version : V12.16.3
My npm version : 6.14.2

I need solution please i Really stack with it

Answer (score 2):

I tried below steps it worked for me I hope it will work for u

1.Try to set npm registry using : npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

2.Check result of curl https://registry.npmjs.org/

3.Clear the cache: npm cache clean --force

4.Try to run npm install

Comment: yes i have try it but it still got npm ERR! code E500 npm ERR! 500 Internal Server Error - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap again

Comment: ?are you trying to install bootsrap??

Comment: no but i try to use npm install but i get that error